# Razor RenderSection within script tags - How to insert script from view into template function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using MVC 3 with the Razor view engine and I would like to inject scripts from multiple views into one centrally defined `$(document).ready();` function in the master page.

I have tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      //OnLoad Script load area
      '@RenderSection("DocumentReady", false)'
    });
</script>
```

In my master view, and then:

```
@section DocumentReady{
    alert('Document is ready!');
}
```

In my view, but unsuprisingly, we get compilation errors due to the javascript not being within a `<script>` tag.

If there are a lot of small view controls that need to run some initialisation script in the `$(document).ready()` function, it would be nice to keep them all together in a single place.

Is there a way to inject javascript to a master view without the surrounding `<script>` tags and without affecting compilation?

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" means. What results are you getting? What did you expect?

Comment: @MEMark, the problem was that it's not easy to put "bare" (not within `<script>` tags javascript in a `RenderSection` area (no intellisense, formatting etc).  But having many views that run some javascript within the `$(document).ready()` event. I have since started to extract my javascript to script files anyway so this isn't a problem for me anymore. Darin has a good solution for anyone still wanting to do something like this.

Comment: I don't think it is right to use Razor statement in Javascript code.
JQuery ready function is run in browser when all DOM is served by the server and browser has no idea what is '@render...'.

Comment: @VitaliyMarkitanov Razor processes the template before the markup is delivered to the client in the response.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You don't need the single quotes around the RenderSection call in your layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        @RenderSection("DocumentReady", false)
    });
</script>
```

and inside the view:

```
@section DocumentReady {
    alert('');
}
```

But it will probably be more readable if you have a scripts section in your layout:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```

and inside the view:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">   
        $(function() {
            alert('');
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I have gone with the second option, it doesn't solve my issue, but it is more readable and my issue is probably not even an problem! I just thought I could reduce the number of "$(document).ready"s.

Answer (score 12):

For example, in your _layout.cshtml :

```
@RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
```

And then in your view :

```
    @section JavaScript
    {
       <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/SomeScript.js")"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/AnotherScript.js")"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">console.log("in the js");</script>
    }
```

Hope that helps