# How can I render Javascript in Blazor server-side?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I have to use a javascript library in a Blazor server-side project.

The library is using to connect to an APP. It needs to initialize by getting the Access Token with a get method in the back-end.

Now the get method can get the access token successfully and the next step is to render it in the font-end to initialize the library.

However, I wanna add a `code` block in the `_Host.cshtml` but it seems do not support at all.

[image]

And then, I tried to modify the code and the `script` block to the `index.cshtml`. Well, now it reports the `script` block will not render on the webpage yet.

[image]

How can I solve this? Would you please help me? Thank you.

---

Blazor is different from the original asp.net core which has not `Rendersection` method.

Here is another question about this:[@RenderSection Equivalent in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912935/rendersection-equivalent-in-blazor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Razor RenderSection within script tags - How to insert script from view into template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923470/razor-rendersection-within-script-tags-how-to-insert-script-from-view-into-tem)

Comment: @OrYaacov I am afraid it seems Blazor has not the RenderSection method, different from the asp.net core yet.

Comment: @OrYaacov Please have a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912935/rendersection-equivalent-in-blazor

Comment: The error message is very very detailed, whats your issue with the error message?! Adding code to components (especially dynamically loaded ones such as ajax before there was razor) was always problematic, independent of technology in use. The only correct way was always to have your JavaScript/TypeScript files separate, compile them to a single (or few) js files, then load them with the application start and react on dom events (thats what jQuery did)

Comment: But generally, your usage of JavaScript indicate that you did not really understand what Blazor is. Blazor compiles (and run on) wasm (Web Assembly), which is native programming which doesn't need JavaScript at all. All of the stuff you can actually do in JavaScript should be possible to do in C# now, so you probably have still the old "mindset" of using JavaScript for dynamic stuff. Blazor server-sided is essentially same as client-sided one, but the "content" will be rendered on the server side and the returned html embedded in the correct place

Comment: @Tseng I have no choice to using C# replace the javascript for the provider of the APP only provides a javascript version library yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to achieve this:
Here is the js:

```
window.TestFunctions = {
    InvokeAlert: function (AlertString) {
        alert(AlertString);
    }
};
```

And here is the code of Blazor:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
                string.Format(NavigationManager.Uri+"Callback/JSInitialise"));

            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = client.SendAsync(request);

            while (true)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_SignatureModel.signature))
                {
                    JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("TestFunctions.InvokeAlert", _SignatureModel.signature);
                    break;
                }
                Task.Delay(200);
            }
        });
    }
```

Well, it works now.

Answer (score 3):

You can add JavaScript only *outside* of Blazor Componenets. You can add them in your index.html or _Host.cshtml . All your external functions would be there, or in components dlls. From Blazor you can just invoke these functions and pass results